# solana-program fails to compile with "experimental" and "unstable" errors

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I have been trying to make solana work for the last few days.
Now I seem to have hit a wall, as I can't find anything about this online.

I believe I have the latest version of everything and I have reinstalled cargo/rust.

Simply following the [anchor docs](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/hello-world) and running `anchor build` is enough to hit these errors:

```
BPF SDK: /usr/lib/solana/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
   Compiling solana-program v1.15.2
error[E0658]: deriving `Default` on enums is experimental
  --> src/nonce/state/current.rs:70:17
   |
70 | #[derive(Debug, Default, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #86985 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86985> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(derive_default_enum)]` to the crate attributes to enable
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Default` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0658]: deriving `Default` on enums is experimental
  --> src/stake/state.rs:19:17
   |
19 | #[derive(Debug, Default, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Clone, Copy, AbiExample)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #86985 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86985> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(derive_default_enum)]` to the crate attributes to enable
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Default` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
  --> src/message/compiled_keys.rs:83:84
   |
83 |                     .filter_map(|(key, meta)| (meta.is_signer && meta.is_writable).then_some(*key)),
   |                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
  --> src/message/compiled_keys.rs:88:77
   |
88 |             .filter_map(|(key, meta)| (meta.is_signer && !meta.is_writable).then_some(*key))
   |                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
  --> src/message/compiled_keys.rs:92:77
   |
92 |             .filter_map(|(key, meta)| (!meta.is_signer && meta.is_writable).then_some(*key))
   |                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
  --> src/message/compiled_keys.rs:96:78
   |
96 |             .filter_map(|(key, meta)| (!meta.is_signer && !meta.is_writable).then_some(*key))
   |                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
  --> src/nonce/state/mod.rs:49:61
   |
49 |                     (recent_blockhash == &data.blockhash()).then_some(data)
   |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
  --> src/stake/tools.rs:31:18
   |
31 |                 .then_some(return_data)
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
   --> src/vote/state/mod.rs:679:40
    |
679 |         let root = (root != Slot::MAX).then_some(root);
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
    = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `solana-program` due to 9 previous errors
```

Edit: By reinstalling solana-cli I got past these errors and can now run `anchor test` successfully on that build.
Nonetheless, the other project that I was trying to build gives me a thousand of these errors:

```
Compiling solana-program v1.15.2
Error: Function _ZN14solana_program4vote5state9VoteState11deserialize17h741ea26b9a7069dbE Stack offset of 6344 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 2248 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN229_$LT$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5.._..$LT$impl$u20$serde..de..Deserialize$u20$for$u20$solana_program..vote..state..vote_state_0_23_5..VoteState0_23_5$GT$..deserialize..__Visitor$u20$as$u20$serde..de..Visitor$GT$9visit_seq17h69b079986e2cc053E Stack offset of 5752 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 1656 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
   Compiling anchor-lang v0.26.0
error[E0412]: cannot find type `c_int` in this scope
 --> src/./aes.rs:3:24
  |
3 | pub const AES_ENCRYPT: c_int = 1;
  |                        ^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this type alias
  |
1 | use std::os::raw::c_int;
  |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `c_int` in this scope
 --> src/./aes.rs:4:24
  |
4 | pub const AES_DECRYPT: c_int = 0;
  |                        ^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this type alias
  |
1 | use std::os::raw::c_int;
  |
```

The only thing I can find online is related to WASM + Libssl but no solution there either for me.

Cargo clean + anchor build resulted in:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `c_int` in this scope
 --> src/./aes.rs:3:24
  |
3 | pub const AES_ENCRYPT: c_int = 1;
  |                        ^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this type alias
  |
1 | use std::os::raw::c_int;
  |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `c_int` in this scope
 --> src/./aes.rs:4:24
  |
4 | pub const AES_DECRYPT: c_int = 0;
  |                        ^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this type alias
  |
1 | use std::os::raw::c_int;
  |
(a lot more omitted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rustc 1.65`, `solana 1.14` and `anchor 0.26` I was able to fix all of this both by:

- reinstalling `solana-cli`
- deleting the directory initialized by `anchor init` and creating it again

Thank you for your time @john and @Callum M

Answer (score 3):

The issue might be with the `rustc` version, you mentioned using the latest version which is 1.67. Try using `rustc 1.65`. Also, Solana 1.15 doesn't currently work with Anchor 0.26.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am using rustc 1.65, solana 1.14 and anchor 0.26. Still errors. Please see my updated build. I can't understand why the differing results in both anchor builds, so I'll delete it and try again. Edit: yup, that did the trick!

Comment: Sorry, not sure about the new errors you're seeing, but the first errors were the exact ones I was also getting. Is the other project also using Anchor 0.26?

Comment: Yes! They're both fine now. I think I'll change my approach from now on and the first I'll be trying in these cases is nuking everything and reinstalling it all, instead of spending 3 days looking for answers. I have never been much fond of that technique because why would it solve anything if I have just installed everything? Well apparently that logic is incomplete, software is complex.

Comment: What I wonder really is how are other people coming up with answers on their own, it really amazes me.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because you're not on a `stable` version of the Solana CLI, which is version 1.14.x. You're probably on a later version.

You can fix this by running `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"`

Ie putting `stable` instead of eg `1.15.2` in the installation instructions: https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Comment: Noo, sorry, I got the stable version. I have updated my answer. Thank you for your time Callum.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite part about Solana OG’s always saying you are using a undatable version is this: Right at the top of Solana’s docs and tuts they always shove the cutting edge release which doesn’t work on mainnet and don’t say a word about it! Now that’s fun!